# Get the Component Information from Intent Action in Android

Tags: java, android

In Android, is it possible to retrieve packagename and activityname using Intent action?

From `ActivityManager` and `PackageManager` to retrieve this info is possible.

Comment: do you mean  if an app (App A) calls your app (app B) via an intent, can app B know the packagename and activityname of App A ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the name from intent :

```
String className = intent.resolveActivity (myContext.getPackageManager()).getClassName();
```